How can I find the cookie file fortunes.u8 online?
When I run M-x cookie RET on my installation of emacs (GNU Emacs 29.3 build 3, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.32, cairo version 1.16.0) - installed from source on Linux Mint 20.3 - I get the error message:

Cannot read file '/usr/share/games/fortunes/fortunes.u8'

This file and its directory are indeed not in /usr/share/games, and I cannot find this file in the source files I used to install Emacs, nor by searching for a file called "fortunes.u8" on my root directory. Neither have I been able to find it on the web by Googling.  Where can this file be found?
I have also looked at C-h f cookies RET in helpful mode, and looked for a node named cookies in info, but was unable to find any reference to the possible source for this file.

fortune is a separate program that isn’t distributed with Emacs. You didn’t say which Linux distribution you use so I can’t give you precise advice, but you should be able to install it using whatever package manager you usually use to install software.

Is it the same as the fortune package on Melpa? I've just installed that but I'm getting the same error message. I'm using LInux Mint 20.3, I'm just fixing some issue with apt then I'll look for a fortune package there too.

Great, I installed fortune with apt, and now cookie works in Emacs as desired. "Don't worry so loud, your roommate can't think" - wise words :-D
